# buildr upload doesn't create maven-metadata.xml

Tags: maven, maven-2, buildr, maven-metadata

I'm trying out buildr on two projects - one has a dependency on the other.

`buildr upload` seems to work ok on project1 but when project2 tries to build it looks for `project1/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml` in my repo, which doesn't exist.

Should I create the maven-metadata.xml file manually? It's not mentioned in the buildr docs.

Here's the output from builder on project2:

```
...
Requesting http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/mydomain/project1/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Connecting to my-repo-server
connected
Downloading from /usr/share/repo/com/mydomain/project1/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Exception while invoking prerequisites of task <Buildr::CompileTask project2:compile => [(classpath deleted)]>
Exception while invoking prerequisites of task <Rake::FileTask ~/Documents/workspace/project2/bin => [project2:compile]>
Exception while invoking prerequisites of task <Rake::Task project2:build => [~/Documents/workspace/project2/bin, project2:test]>
Exception while invoking prerequisites of task <Rake::Task default => [build]>
Buildr aborted!
Net::SFTP::StatusException : Net::SFTP::StatusException (2, "no such file")
[Stacktrace deleted]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, buildr doesn't create this type of Maven artifacts.